# Linksys E4200 does not seem to support 4TB drives

Tags: router, usb-flash-drive

I connected a Hitachi 4TB USB 3.0 drive to E4200 router using USB but get alert saying it does not support it.

Anyone has a fix or solution for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  This product does not support drives > 2tb unless CISCO provide a new version of the firmware.  The problem is that drives > 2tb use "GPT" (guided partition tables)/"Advanced Format" to be able to access more then 2tb with reasonable performance.  The firmware for this device does not support GPT.

Have a look at http://homecommunity.cisco.com/t5/Wireless-Routers/E4200-support-for-GPT-formatted-hard-drives/td-p/518275